# How to handle platform specific code under revision control

Tags: php, svn, version-control

We have web developers on both Windows and Linux using SVN. Some PHP files reference a local path (e.g. Smarty/Geolocation libraries) and hence are different on their respective platforms. We need to keep these files under revision but the developers are starting to just add the svn:ignore attribute on these specific files to prevent conflicts. The only solution I can come up with is to put some code to determine which OS is being run but this seems like bloat for production code.

```
if (PHP_OS == "WIN32" || PHP_OS == "WINNT") {
        define('SMARTY_DIR', 'c:/xampp/smarty/');
    } else { 
        define('SMARTY_DIR', '/usr/local/lib/php/Smarty/');
    }
```

I'd love to hear how others have solved this problem.

Comment: I do a similar approach based on domain name for my dev, staging and production servers I would recommend putting all the configuration that is platform dependant into one php file, so it isn't spread throughout the code

Comment: have a per-platform configuration files like _.../WIN32/platf.php_ and variables, somewhat like $PLATF_CFG_DIR (relative to the current file) and $PLATF which when used together point to the platform specific settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this is with a config.php.template file.  The template file is version controlled and developers will copy it to config.php for their local settings.

Comment: ...and config.php is svn:ignored.